# Usando inputs para acessar dados de arquivo csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo, csv

tenho um arquivo csv com dados meteorológicos desde o ano 1961 até 2016 e preciso receber inputs de um intervalo com o mes e o ano inicial e o mes e ano final e permitir que o usuario escolha se ele quer ver  todos os dados,  apenas os de precipitação, apenas os de temperatura ou  apenas os de umidade e vento para o período informado. tenho isso por enquanto:

```
    dados = {}
with open('dados.csv') as csv:
    print(csv.readlines())
    for linha in csv:
        aux = linha[:-1].split(';')
        data = aux[0]
        precip = aux[1]
        minima = aux[2]
        maxima = aux[3]
        umidade = aux[6]
        vento = aux[7]
        dados = [data, precip, minima, minima, maxima, umidade, vento]
```

Answer (score 0):

Crias um array com as linhas da tabela. Usas a função input() para obter o input do utilizador e depois mostras os dados correspondentes.

```
dados = {}
linhas = []
with open('dados.csv') as csv:
    print(csv.readlines())
    for linha in csv:
        aux = linha[:-1].split(';')
        data = aux[0]
        precip = aux[1]
        minima = aux[2]
        maxima = aux[3]
        umidade = aux[6]
        vento = aux[7]
        dados = [data, precip, minima, minima, maxima, umidade, vento]
        linhas.append(dados)

mode = input("Digite [1] para ver todos os dados. Digite [2] para precipitação. Digite [3] para temperaturas. Digite [4] para umidade. Digite [5] para vento.")

if mode == '1':
    for linha in linhas:
        print(linha)
elif mode == '2':
    for linha in linhas:
        print(linha[0], linha[1])
elif mode == '3':
    for linha in linhas:
        print(linha[0], linha[2], linha[3], linha[4])
elif mode == '4':
    for linha in linhas:
        print(linha[0], linha[5])
elif mode == '5':
    for linha in linhas:
        print(linha[0], linha[6])
```